# How do I upload a new file using Box's OneCloud AppToApp android sdk without first starting in the Box app

Tags: android, box-api

On iOS, the Box OneCloudAppToApp sdk allows for bringing up the box app's save file dialog without first starting in the box app.  Is this possible on android or do I always have to start from the box app?

The root of my problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to get a reference to a OneCloudData instance without it first being passed in by box.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sibling of the OneCloudData object that allows you to create a new file in the same directory as the original file. There are 2 main limitations though:

1. You have to save an OneCloudData object previously passed from Box or you can restore it from it's token.
2. You can only save in the same directory as the original file.

You can also use the object's `launch` method to start the Box app which lets the user browse his folders and chooser where to make a *create new file* request.

I am afraid those are the only options on the Android AppToApp's sdk